# How to get contextual data within the ConversationAdded event

Tags: lync

We have a module that generates Conversation with users including adding Contectual Data to the conversation.  The conversation is generated with the below line of code,

```
IAsyncResult ar = automation.BeginStartConversation(AutomationModalities.InstantMessage,singleParticipant, modalitySettings, BeginConversationCallBack, automation);
```

Within another application/service we are listening for conversations getting created, which is the void Conversations_ConversationAdded(object sender, ConversationManagerEventArgs e) event handler.  This event handler is called whenever a conversation is created, within this event handler we wire up some more event handlers for context data such as,

```
e.Conversation.InitialContextSent += new EventHandler<InitialContextEventArgs>  (conversation_InitialContextSent);
e.Conversation.InitialContextReceived += new EventHandler<InitialContextEventArgs>(conversation_InitialContextReceived);
e.Conversation.ContextDataSent += new EventHandler<ContextEventArgs>(Conversation_ContextDataSent);
e.Conversation.ContextDataReceived += new EventHandler<ContextEventArgs>(Conversation_ContextDataReceived);
```

however none of the events are raised when new conversations are created by the method mentioned previously.  I'm trying to find a means to get the contextual data in the conversation but I'm having a hard time doing so.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong or have another means to suggest?

Troy

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the below post says a UI-suppressed Lync (2010) client cannot receive contextual data:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/dfeb0603-b4ef-44f1-97c1-2555991a221a/how-to-send-custom-data-from-one-uisuppressed-application-to-another

The below page implies only the InitialContextReceived event is not sent, however subsequent data may be received. See the comment "This event is not raised in this code when Lync is not in UI suppressed mode.". Note that this is for 2013 and I haven't tried this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/jj933248.aspx